# Php age check form

Tags: php, time, twig

I'm giving my first steps on php and I got this project where, although I understand what is being done, for some reason it does not work.

```
$app->post('/age/', function($lang) use($app) {

        $action = $app->request()->post('action');
        $remember = $app->request->post('remember') === 'on';

        if ($action === 'Yes') {

            setcookie('AgeCheck', 'true', time()+60*60*24*30, '/'); //Expire in 1 month
            $_SESSION['age'] = 'true';

            $app->redirect(urldecode($app->request()->get('return')) ?: "/$lang");
        }
        else if ($action === 'Enter') {

            $limit = (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) * 18;

            $dob = $app->request->post('dob');

            if ($lang === 'us') {
                $dob = \DateTime::createFormFormat('mdy', $dob);
                $limit = (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) * 21;
            }
            else
            {
                $dob = \DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $dob);
            }

            if ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit)
            {
                setcookie('AgeCheck', 1, (60*60*24*365)/12); //Expire in 1 month
                $_SESSION['age'] = 1;

                $app->redirect(urldecode($app->request()->get('return')) ?: "/$lang");
            }
        }

        $app->redirect("/$lang/underage");
```

This should, in theory,redirect the user to the proper page if he passes the age restriction, but it always redirects him to the underage page.

The issue is, most definitely, in here: `if ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$dob = \DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $dob);` is not fomated properly. `dmy` doesn't exist. In this context is should be `d-m-Y`. Thus `\DateTime::createFromFormat` will always return false. Not to mention `DateTime::craeateFromFormat` will return an array of 3 values not a int. But due to how PHP does typejuggling you didn't catch on to the error.

Comment: The more interesting part here is that `((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit)` is actually `true`(in this context). So maybe the `$action` is not `Enter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check every line of your code.
Your key condition is:

```
if ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit)
{
    setcookie('DrambuieAgeCheck', 1, (60*60*24*365)/12); //Expire in 1 month
    $_SESSION['age'] = 1;
    $app->redirect(urldecode($app->request()->get('return')) ?: "/$lang");
}
```

So before that, just echo/var_dump $dob->getTimestamp(), and $limit. Everything will be clear for you.
If something wrong with $dob, check what is returned by $_POST['dob'].

Example:

```
var_dump($dob->getTimestamp());
var_dump($app->request->post('dob'));
var_dump($dob->getTimestamp());
var_dump(time());
echo 'condition result:';
var_dump(((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()));
if ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit)
```

You will see most important variables in condition, and condition it self

Comment: As I said, I'm fairly new to php and have no idea how to echo out those values, since I'm submitting a form. What I'm doing to check them is simply `$app->redirect("/$lang/underage?dob=$dob?limit=$limit");` and defining them bellow `$remember`. And if I create something like `$time = (time() - $dob->getTimestapm())`, it always gives me an error or shows nothing at all (blank page).

Comment: check what i added before your if ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit) condition

Comment: For some reason I can't get the values from var_dump, but I managed to do this: `$dob = $app->request->post('dob');
        $dobDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy', $dob);
        $dobTime = $dobDate->getTimestamp();
        $limit = (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) * 18;
        $time = time();
        $limitTime = $time - $limit;
        $dobTime2 = $time - $dobTime;
        $result = $dobTime2 >= $limit;`

And print it on the url with `$app->redirect("/$lang/underage?dob=$dob?dobTimestamp=$dobTime?dobTime2=$dobTime2?limit=$limit?limitTime=$limitTime?result=$result");`

Result on next comment

Comment: `underage?dob=101080?dobTimestamp=340021257?dobTime2=1103587200?limit=567648000?limitTime=875960457?result=1`

So it all seems to be working, since its returning `true`...

Comment: put: die(); after echo so you will see variables for sure

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue. Everything was correct, but it wasn't even entering the if, since the $action was not enter, but submit. I'l still keep @Daimos answer as correct.

> The more interesting part here is that ((time() - $dob->getTimestamp()) >= $limit) is actually true(in this context). So maybe the $action is not Enter? –  Andrew

This was the key to solve it, after I've tried everything and checked that it was all correct.